# How to create a training set for recommendation system of retail banking products

Tags: banking, recommendation-engine

When we use recommender systems for retail banking products (life insurance, mutual fund, lockers etc) some of the products are one time purchases so if I need to create a recommender system that will predict what will be the purchases in the next 3 months how do I go about it?